# Is there a way to change the color of an HTML5 textbox watermark?

Tags: css, html, forms

If I have an HTML5 text box as follows

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="mytextbox" placeholder"MyTextBox"/>
</form>
```

is there a way using HTML or CSS to change the color of the placeholder/watermark from the default light gray?

Comment: This may help!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css

Comment: tagged as duplicate of that one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2610741/1241793).

Long story short, you need to use CSS Selectors to apply the rules to each browser, which handles the process differently.

```css
input.mytextbox::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* WebKit browsers */
  color: red;
}

input.mytextbox:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
  color: red;
  opacity: 1;
}

input.mytextbox::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
  color: red;
  opacity: 1;
}

input.mytextbox:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input class="mytextbox" type="text" name="mytextbox" placeholder="MyTextBox"/>
```